# Android: get view's text in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm setting the same `onClick` to various buttons, when I try to create a condition to check the text colour of the clicked view (which is a button) I cant, the only options regarding text are `v.getTextAlignment` and `v.getTextDiretion` , how do I `getTextColor`?

Comment: its actually getCurrentTextColor()

Comment: Doesn't exist either

Comment: have u casted your View object with Button?

Comment: yes just like Rick Canchez suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
((Button) v).getCurrentTextColor();
```

Comment: what type are you using for the color?

Comment: I'm setting the color straight from the hex code. `button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));`

Comment: I just checked button.getCurrentTextColor() will return int which is a text color of the button. How are you checking the color condition btw?

Comment: `button.getCurrentTextColor()` will, but `(Button) v.getCurrentTextColor()` for some reason won't. Like this: `if(v.getTextColor == Color.WHITE)`

Comment: its actually `((Button) v).getCurrentTextColor()`

Comment: Ofc it is, I was doing the parentheses wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
   v.getCurrentTextColor();
```

Comment: Doesn't exist either

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
ColorStateList mColorList = mBtn.getTextColors();
int color = mColorList.getDefaultColor();
```

-1 equals Color.WHITE

Comment: I don't understand, how do I use this int in the condition?

Comment: if(color==Color.RED) or switch(color)